# mpmath not found while compiling with buildozer

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

i've coded a simple equation solver that works with sympy , i added a gui with kivy.
when i try to compile it with buildozer it shows me this.

## Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,sympy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/ilyass/Desktop/monapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21

---

i think the problem comes either from 
this :The requirements (certifi, mpmath) were not found as recipes, they will be installed with pip.
or :[WARNING]: lld not found, linking without it. Consider installing lld if linker errors occur.
ps: i have both sympy and mpmath in requirements and installed both

Comment: post your full log to have a better look at the error

Comment: https://pastebin.com/c233wKbn

Comment: STDOUT:
Please install the mpmath package with a version >= 0.19

Comment: if you have it installed, check the version or install a fresh

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zPAvDtX2 this is my version of mpmath and when i try to uninstall  it shows a error

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answers ! i solved the problem

Comment: @Cosinusbasicfunction How did you solved this problem?

Comment: Just remove mpmath and sympy from the requirements and move their files in the folder where you compile and done !!